# How to speed up loading of Marshal objects in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, marshalling

I have a mongoid model/class in my Rails application. It looks like this:

```
class Operation
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  extend Mongoid::MarshallableField

  marshallable_field :message

  def load_message
    message
  end
end
```

`message` contains an array of several thousands of elements, so it has been converted into a byte stream with [Marshal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Marshal.html).

I need to be able to load `message`fast, but currently it takes approx. 1,4 seconds to load, e.g. with the `load_message` method as displayed above.

How could I speed things up?

For your reference, here is my configuration:

```
## app/lib/mongoid/marshallable_field.rb

module Mongoid
  module MarshallableField

    def marshallable_field(field_name, params = {})

      set_method_name = "#{field_name}=".to_sym
      get_method_name = "#{field_name}".to_sym
      attr_name = "__#{field_name}_marshallable_path".to_sym

      send :define_method, set_method_name do |obj|
        if Rails.env == "development" || Rails.env == "test"
          path = File.expand_path(Rails.public_path + "/../file_storage/#{Time.now.to_i}-#{id}.class_dump")
        elsif Rails.env == "production"
          path = "/home/ri/prod/current/file_storage/#{Time.now.to_i}-#{id}.class_dump"
        end

        f = File.new(path, "w")
        Marshal.dump(obj, f)
        f.close
        update_attribute(attr_name, path)
        path
      end

      send :define_method, get_method_name do 
        if self[attr_name] != nil
          file = File.open(self[attr_name], "r")

          begin
            Marshal.load(file)
          rescue ArgumentError => e
            Rails.logger.error "Error unmarshalling a field #{attr_name}: #{e}"
            nil
          end
        else
          Rails.logger.error "self[attr_name] is nil"
          nil
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```